# How can I compensate for a formicids permanent stasis effect?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

I've been playing DCSS trunk lately, and have been trying formicids out. Since they have a clear predilection for armor and not especially great spellcasting attributes, as well as the complete inability to teleport, blink, haste, or berserk, what are my best options for panic buttons? The usual religious melee user panics of Trog's berserk and Oka's finesse are not options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't played with Formicids yet, but I would try with Cheibriados. His (her?) [Step from time](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Cheibriados#Given_Abilities) is awesome, and you've already lost the ability to haste and berserk yourself. Plus, Chei is awesome with these hybrid capable races

According to [the wiki](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Formicid), these also work:

- [Lugonu](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Lugonu#Given_Abilities)'s Bend Space
- [Dithmenos](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Dithmenos#Given_Abilities)'s Shadow Step
- [Passage of Golubria](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Passage_of_Golubria)
- Boots of [jumping](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Jumping)

Just remember that the wiki is not the most up to date source :P

Another thing that might not be worth it, but for the sake of completeness, is learning translocation spells that work on others:

- [Teleport other](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Teleport_Other): not very good since is resistible, is for one monster and it *could* reappear next to you.
- [Dispersal](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Dispersal): it works on monsters adjacent to you and if it fails it blinks them, else they are instantly teleported.
- [Disjunction](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Disjunction): gives you an aura that tries to keep enemies away from you (not very useful if you're melee). Hard to cast/master.